# Hide Meteor.users and other information on client

Tags: meteor

By default a user can run `"Meteor.users"` in a browser console and he would have access to a lot of user information. How can I secure user information in a Meteor app?

Answer (score 1):

Once you remove the automatic publishing you can specify specific queries that are returned to the client. Meteor recomposes this information on the client-side into a "miniMongo" collection that acts like the server-side Mongo DB. The difference being that the miniMongo can only "see" the information that is published and that it subscribes to.

The nice thing about Meteor is that the miniMongo automatically stays in sync with the server-side DB once you have setup your publish / subscribe. When the client accesses the information, it is instantaneous because it is accessing the local miniMongo collection. Changes are then resolved by Meteor in the background between the local and server side collection / DB.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is remove the insecure package.

```
mrt remove insecure
```

After you do that a few things will probably break since you're no longer publishing everything to the client.  You'll have to setup publications and subscriptions.